# What can I do that don't block users in using instagram whith like IPs in my network?

Tags: proxy, instagram

I have a network in my server with one static IP and more than 20 person using 30 instagram account inside it.

But instagram suspicious or blocks more of them.

1- I know I can use proxies in server to solve this, But can I use a world proxy lifetime without monthly or yearly period?

2- In telegram, we can install MTPro protocol for using it. Is a protocol or way that don't need a proxy for using my users in server instagram?

Comment: I made an API that lists all the proxies that works with instagram:
https://api.lityapp.com/proxies

The validation schedule runs every day.